# how to import python lists to table(tr) in HTML - Python

Tags: python, html

I have a list in python, how to pass it to **HTML** table in Python.

```
list1 = [['Career', 'school', 5, 'A'], ['Career', 'higher', 4, 'A'], ['Career', 'college', 3, 'A'], ['Edu', 'Blr', 20, 'A']]

 html =  """\<html><head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;}th, td {padding: 5px;text-align: left;}</style></head><table style="width:30%"><tr><th>Category</th><th>Sub-Category</th><th>Sessions</th><th>Org_name</th></tr><tr># The list should print here </tr></table></body></html> """
```

The output should be in table like

`Category|Sub-Category|Sessions|Org_name
Career  |School      |5       |A
Career  |Higher      |4       |A
Career  |College     |3       |A
Edu     |Blr         |20      |A`

Please help me.

Comment: Are you using Jinja template?

Comment: @Rakesh: No, its direct html in python with other data tables which contains variable passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution without any third-party libraries:

```
list1 = [['Career', 'school', 5, 'A'], ['Career', 'higher', 4, 'A'], ['Career', 'college', 3, 'A'], ['Edu', 'Blr', 20, 'A']]
headers = ['Category', 'Sub-Category', 'Sessions', 'Org_name']
style = """
 td, th {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
"""
template = """
<html>
  <style>
    {}
  </style>
  <body> 
    <table>   
    {}
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
""".format(style, '\t<tr>'+'\n'.join('\t\t<th>{}</th>'.format(i) for i in headers)+'\n\t</tr>'+'\n'.join('\t<tr>'+'\n'.join('\t\t<td>{}</td>'.format(c) for c in i)+'\n\t</tr>' for i in list1[1:])) 
with open('test_file.html', 'w') as f:
  f.write(template)
```

When opening `test_file.html` in a browser, the result below is produced:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
{% for lists in list1 %}
    <tr>
    {%for li in lists %}
    <td>{{li}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: did you check this? @Praveen Reddy

Comment: its coming as invalid syntax on the first line. The code should be used inside the HTML

Comment: and when you use render_template you should pass the list1 to html file

Comment: yes , i have used inside HTML. but its showing as invalid syntax on the first line

Comment: yes i am passing list1 to html file but for syntax is correct ?. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a string of HTML inside your Python program, easiest way I can think of is using Pandas and its [`to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df.columns = ['Category', 'Sub-Category', 'Sessions', 'Org_name']
html = df.to_html(index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list1,columns=["Category","Sub-Category","Sessions","Org_name"])

print(df.to_html()) #it will print html tags for the df

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Sub-Category</th>
      <th>Sessions</th>
      <th>Org_name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>Career</td>
      <td>school</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Career</td>
      <td>higher</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>Career</td>
      <td>college</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>Edu</td>
      <td>Blr</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The list is dynamic. The list comes from SQL query. I just gave sample list. the list may increase or decrease as well.

Comment: get the sql table colums and replace the column values

Comment: Let me know how to do it using for loops iteration please.

Comment: you can create a empty dataframe `df=pd.DataFrame()` then loop like `for row in rows:df.append(row,ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Please approve the answer